# how to generate correlated binary vectors with R using rmvbin?

Tags: r, binary, simulation, correlation

I am trying to generate 10 vectors of binary data with specified correlation coefficients between each 2 of these vectors. 
I have defined a correlation matrix "m" 10*10 which contains the correlations between the 10 vectors, and i have used it as an input to this function:

```
X<-rmvbin(1000, margprob=c(rep(0.5,10)), bincorr=m)
```

The problem is that when I run "cor(xI", I get a matrix different from the correlation matrix "m" that I have already set. I'm not quite sure if I had correctly defined **margprob**. I guess this is where the problem comes from and I don't know how should I define it otherwise. Any help, please ?

Comment: Everything seems to work fine. `m` is the theoretical variance-covariance matrix, so `cor(x)` should be more similar to `m` if you replace 1000 with, say, 100000. If you want `cor(x)` to be exactly equal to `m`, then that's a different matter and doesn't seem to be available with this function (it is, e.g., in `rmvnorm` from `MASS`, but that for the multivariate normal distribution).

Comment: Thank you. I don't want it to be exactly the same, but for some vectors i found really different correlations from the ones i fixed. For example between vectors 1 and 9 i wanted a correlation coefficient equals to 0.8 and i got 0.53. Is there any other way to get the correlation coefficients i want ?

Comment: I'd suggest first to convince yourself that correlations are really similar when you replace 1000 with something much larger. If `m` is fixed, then it looks like nothing much can be done with a smaller sample; although you can always fix a seed as in `set.seed(123)` and perhaps with some seed you will get more satisfying results, but that's a kind of cheating. It most cases all what should matter is that you do a correct thing theoretically.